# How to programmatically consent and call graph api "memberOf" endpoint

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, access-token, azure-ad-graph-api, microsoft-identity-platform

My requirement is to call "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/memberOf" using Microsoft.Identity.Client and am doing as below and it fails to fetch the appropriate response.

```
GetToken.cs

     var result = await client.AcquireTokenOnBehalfOf(new string[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" }, userAssertion)
                        .WithSendX5C(true)
                        .ExecuteAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    return result.AccessToken;
```

[image]

Question : For the above graph api call to work , I have consent because it asks for but how to consent using Microsoft.Identity.Client?

Comment: You need to add permissions of the application in the portal first, and the user will consent when signing in. Or you could grant admin consent.

Comment: @PamelaPeng How can I grant admin consent programmatically?

Comment: You could follow [this](https://samcogan.com/provide-admin-consent-fora-azure-ad-applications-programmatically/). If you grant admin consent, it does not require consent when you call MS Graph API.

Answer (score 0):

To grant consent programmatically, you can use the Microsoft Graph API (e.g. with the [Microsoft Graph SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/sdks-overview)).

When you consent for an application to access your data, three things may happen:

1. A service principal is ensured to exist for the client application (the "client" is the app which is requesting the permissions). If it does not exist, it is created: [Create servicePrincipal](https://learn.microsoft.com/graph/api/serviceprincipal-post-serviceprincipals?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)
2. If the client requires delegated permissions, they are granted. Delegated permissions can be granted on behalf of all users, or on behalf of specific users: [Create a delegated permission grant](https://learn.microsoft.com/graph/api/oauth2permissiongrant-post?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http).
3. If the client requires app-only permissions (also known as "app roles"), they are granted. Application permissions (app roles) are granted with an app role assignment: [Grant an appRoleAssignment to a service principal](https://learn.microsoft.com/graph/api/serviceprincipal-post-approleassignedto?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

Warning: Granting consent is a very privileged operation. For an application to be able perform the steps described above, that application would itself be highly privileged.