# How Can I make flask API to access GraphAPI for get excel file content

Tags: python, flask, azure-ad-graph-api

I want to make an API for access to graph API but without a login page and user authentication.

```
token_url = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantID>/oauth2/v2.0/token"
token_data = {
 'grant_type': 'client_credentials',
 'client_id': app_id,
 'client_secret': client_secret,
 'scope':'https://graph.microsoft.com/.default',

}
token_r = requests.post(token_url, data=token_data)

token = token_r.json().get('access_token')
print(token)

users_url = **"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drive/items/<FileID>/workbook/worksheets('Sheet1')/range(address='a1:v500')/UsedRange(valuesOnly=true)?$format=atom,$select=values"**

headers = {
 'Authorization': 'Bearer {}'.format(token)
}

authHeader = {
    'Content-Type':'application/json',
    'Authorization':"Bearer " + token,
    'ExpiresOn':str(token_r.json().get('expires_in'))
}

k = requests.get(users_url, headers=authHeader)
print(k.text)
```

Now it returns **{'error': {'code': 'AccessDenied', 'message': 'Either scp or roles claim need to be present in the token.',... }}**

I know, I need to provide Grant Admin consent from Azure but We don't have access Admin portal. So Is there any other way to read the XLSX file without login or Admin consent?

Answer (score 0):

Few things to note here-

1. In Client credential flow - tokens will have application claims i.e. running in context of an application. Therefore, you cannot use /me endpoint here. Try using /users endpoint in such cases or use other Oauth 2.0 flows (like authorization code flows) to obtain beaer token.
2. To get a driveitem resource, below permissions are needed. Make sure you add them to scope while obtaining bearer token.
   [image]

Comment: Thanks, Shweta for the Quick reply. I edited the question with the new scenario. Please check and kindly guide me.

Comment: Maybe you can try consenting programmatically. You can also leverage PowerShell in this case. See if this is helpful - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65302583/how-to-programmatically-consent-and-call-graph-api-memberof-endpoint